# Impersonate current user in windows 10 service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, impersonation, windows-identity

the following is a windows services which maps the home drive and a W drive. Everything works well if i execute the code under a user. Since this is a service running under local system I used an impersonation class to call it. The impersonation works perfectly when creating shortcuts to the drives on the desktop, however it will not map the drives using net use command. I want the drives to be mapped non persistent. I have attached my complete code below along with the impersonation class. Is there a way to map these drives non persistent under current user using impersonation?

```
namespace HdriveMapService2
{
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {


        using (ImpersonationUtils.ImpersonateCurrentUser())


            //check if Hdrive exists

            if (!Directory.Exists(@"H:\"))

        {
            //ping Hdrive server

            try
            {   //find current domain controller
                using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
                {

                    string controller = context.ConnectedServer;

                    //ping current domain controller
                    Ping ping = new Ping();
                    PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(controller);

                    if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)

                    {



                            try

                            {

                                    //get current username

                                    string username = Environment.UserName;

                                    Console.WriteLine(username);
                                    Console.ReadLine();

                                    //Lookup current username in AD

                                    DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();
                                    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection);
                                    search.Filter = "(cn=" + username + ")";


                                    //Search for User's Home Directory 

                                    string[] requiredProperties = new string[] { "homeDirectory" };
                                    foreach (String property in requiredProperties)
                                        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(property);
                                    SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

                                    // If home directory info is not blank

                                    if (result != null)

                                    {


                                        //pass the homedirectory path into a variable

                                        string path = "";
                                        foreach (String property in requiredProperties)
                                            foreach (Object myCollection in result.Properties[property])
                                                path = (myCollection.ToString());


                                    //map Hdrive (non persistent map)




                                        //create a desktop shortcut to Hdrive

                                        var wsh = new IWshShell_Class();
                                        IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut = wsh.CreateShortcut(
                                        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\H Drive.lnk") as IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut;
                                        shortcut.TargetPath = path;
                                        shortcut.Save();

                                        //map Wdrive (non persistent map)



                                        //create a desktop shortcut to Wdrive

                                        var wsh2 = new IWshShell_Class();
                                        IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut2 = wsh2.CreateShortcut(
                                        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\W Drive.lnk") as IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut;
                                        shortcut2.TargetPath = @"\\path\path-groups";
                                        shortcut2.Save();

                                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net.exe", "use /persistent:NO H: " + path);
                                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net.exe", @"use /persistent:NO W: \\path\path-groups");

                                }

                                }

                            catch (Exception)

                            {
                                //do nothing
                            }
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
  }


//Impersonation Class
public static class ImpersonationUtils
{
private const int SW_SHOW = 5;
private const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
private const int TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
private const int TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
private const int STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 0x00000001;
private const int STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK = 0x00000040;
private const int CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400;
private const int TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x0004;
private const int TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x0010;
private const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x0020;
private const int TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x0040;
private const int TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x0080;
private const int TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x0100;
private const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;
private const int TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS =
    STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED |
    TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY |
    TOKEN_DUPLICATE |
    TOKEN_IMPERSONATE |
    TOKEN_QUERY |
    TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE |
    TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES |
    TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS |
    TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT |
    TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
{
    public IntPtr hProcess;
    public IntPtr hThread;
    public int dwProcessId;
    public int dwThreadId;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public int nLength;
    public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
    public bool bInheritHandle;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct STARTUPINFO
{
    public int cb;
    public string lpReserved;
    public string lpDesktop;
    public string lpTitle;
    public int dwX;
    public int dwY;
    public int dwXSize;
    public int dwYSize;
    public int dwXCountChars;
    public int dwYCountChars;
    public int dwFillAttribute;
    public int dwFlags;
    public short wShowWindow;
    public short cbReserved2;
    public IntPtr lpReserved2;
    public IntPtr hStdInput;
    public IntPtr hStdOutput;
    public IntPtr hStdError;
}

private enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
{
    SecurityAnonymous,
    SecurityIdentification,
    SecurityImpersonation,
    SecurityDelegation

}

private enum TOKEN_TYPE
{
    TokenPrimary = 1,
    TokenImpersonation
}

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(
    IntPtr hToken,
    string lpApplicationName,
    string lpCommandLine,
    ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
    ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
    bool bInheritHandles,
    int dwCreationFlags,
    IntPtr lpEnvironment,
    string lpCurrentDirectory,
    ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
    out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(
    IntPtr hExistingToken,
    int dwDesiredAccess,
    ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
    int ImpersonationLevel,
    int dwTokenType,
    ref IntPtr phNewToken);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool OpenProcessToken(
    IntPtr ProcessHandle,
    int DesiredAccess,
    ref IntPtr TokenHandle);

[DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool CreateEnvironmentBlock(
        ref IntPtr lpEnvironment,
        IntPtr hToken,
        bool bInherit);

[DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool DestroyEnvironmentBlock(
        IntPtr lpEnvironment);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool CloseHandle(
    IntPtr hObject);

private static void LaunchProcessAsUser(string cmdLine, IntPtr token, IntPtr envBlock, int sessionId)
{
    var pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
    var saProcess = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
    var saThread = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
    saProcess.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(saProcess);
    saThread.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(saThread);

    var si = new STARTUPINFO();
    si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
    si.lpDesktop = @"WinSta0\Default";
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;

    if (!CreateProcessAsUser(
        token,
        null,
        cmdLine,
        ref saProcess,
        ref saThread,
        false,
        CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
        envBlock,
        null,
        ref si,
        out pi))
    {
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "CreateProcessAsUser failed");
    }
}

internal static void LaunchAsCurrentUser(Process process)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

internal static void LaunchAsCurrentUser(string v1, string v2)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private static IDisposable Impersonate(IntPtr token)
{
    var identity = new WindowsIdentity(token);
    return identity.Impersonate();
}

private static IntPtr GetPrimaryToken(Process process)
{
    var token = IntPtr.Zero;
    var primaryToken = IntPtr.Zero;

    if (OpenProcessToken(process.Handle, TOKEN_DUPLICATE, ref token))
    {
        var sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        sa.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);

        if (!DuplicateTokenEx(
            token,
            TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS,
            ref sa,
            (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation,
            (int)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
            ref primaryToken))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "DuplicateTokenEx failed");
        }

        CloseHandle(token);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "OpenProcessToken failed");
    }

    return primaryToken;
}

private static IntPtr GetEnvironmentBlock(IntPtr token)
{
    var envBlock = IntPtr.Zero;
    if (!CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref envBlock, token, false))
    {
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "CreateEnvironmentBlock failed");
    }
    return envBlock;
}

public static void LaunchAsCurrentUser(string cmdLine)
{
    var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer")[0];
    if (process != null)
    {
        var token = GetPrimaryToken(process);
        if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            var envBlock = GetEnvironmentBlock(token);
            if (envBlock != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                LaunchProcessAsUser(cmdLine, token, envBlock, process.SessionId);
                if (!DestroyEnvironmentBlock(envBlock))
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "DestroyEnvironmentBlock failed");
                }
            }

            CloseHandle(token);
        }
    }
}

public static IDisposable ImpersonateCurrentUser()
{
    var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer")[0];
    if (process != null)
    {
        var token = GetPrimaryToken(process);
        if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return Impersonate(token);
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("Could not find explorer.exe");
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `\\server\share` paths?

Comment: because you (for example) cannot run batch files on them... some stuff only works on what the system believes to be a local drive.

Answer (score 0):

1. What current user are you impersonating? The service is started under Local System, probably in the background - won't the current user be the same Local System account?
2. To map UNC path to a drive the service account (let's say it's Local System) needs access rights to these UNC shares. Does it have them?

I advise you to add some debug trace and see what account you code is factually running under and then verify that this account is allowed at least to see these UNC paths/shares.

Comment: Current active user, current user account and local system are different. I'm looking to mainly map the user's home drive from active directory which only the current user has access to. Impersonation class is able to map a shortcut of the current drive on desktop, however not able to map it as a mapped drive.

Comment: If your service starts as a Local System (in a non-interactive session) and then impersonates the currently logged in user it may have a delegation problem. Try                                 string level = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().ImpersonationLevel); - you probably need delegation to reach remote share.

Comment: thanks for the reply, Where should i put this code? in the impersonation class?

Comment: right after using (ImpersonationUtils.ImpersonateCurrentUser()) - if your level is Impersonation instead of Delegation, the code will be impersonating locally, but for remote host it will still be Local System (the local computer name, really). I'm not sure where exactly delegation vs impersonation is specified in the WinApi, you'll need to google into it a bit.

Comment: looks like i'm not able to get delegation to work. looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach to solve the issue. I complied the drive map as an executable. Built a windows service with a timer. Added the executable as a file in the service setup project and made the service call that executable under impersonation and all works perfectly. If anyone has any questions or is struggling with something similar, this may help. I'll be happy to provide details if needed.

Thanks,

Ray

Comment: Not a useful answer. Your code might happen to work if the Windows starts and a user logs in. But what might happen if no user logs on or two users log on remotely? Querying `explorer.exe` is a simple but not reliable way.

Comment: I am open to suggestions for a more reliable solution. Please let me know if you have any. Thanks

Comment: Win32 API such as https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833(v=vs.85).aspx can reliably return the information. You can either PInvoke them yourself, or use an open source library that wraps them.

Comment: I will check it out, Thank you!